# Why my program throws "incompatible integer to pointer conversion" error when using function of 2D array parameter?

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, parameters, parameter-passing

I am getting the following error:
`warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int (*)[50]'`

I am trying to pass a function that will traverse each cell in the 2D array & count the values in the cells that are divisible by 6 but not by 5. For some reason, I am getting the above error but don't know why & can't find anything online related to the error.
I think C is weird when it comes to 2D arrays and I think it has something to do with that but any advise would be appreciated.

My code is below :

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int arrayCounter(int arr[40][50]) {
    int counter = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 50 ; j ++) {
            if(arr[i][j] % 6  == 0 && arr[i][j] % 5 !=0 ) {
                counter ++;
            }
    
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    int array[40][50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
            printf("%d", arrayCounter(array[i][j]));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't try much other than add '&' in front of the array[i][j] to see if that would solve the error but to no avail. I am not a beginner of C but coming back to it after years of not using the language at all.

One of my biggest confusions is why the program is stating my parameter is a pointer for the first array when its clearly defined in the function.

Comment: `array[i][j]` is a single integer, not a 2d array of integers. What is `arrayCounter` supposed to do? It doesn't seem like something you would call in a loop. It would be a good idea to adopt a consistent formatting policy. Code that is easier to read is easier to debug, maintain, and extend.

Comment: @RetiredNinja this code is for a class ultimately , the arrayCounter function is to traverse a 40x50 2d array & count the values in each index which are divisible by 6 & not divisible by 5 .

Comment: I suspect that you want to output the return value of your function once, as the expected output for an exercise. How often do you think that your program is going to output it? I suspect that you want to give the whole array as parameter to your function (or a reference/pointer to it), so that it can be analysed and the result of the analysis returned for being output in `main()`. What do you think that your `main()` gives as parameter? What ( in contrast to that) do you think that your function expects as parameter? I ask these questions to a) make you think b) find out what the program does

Comment: So, since the function iterates through the whole array does it make sense that you would call it 2000 times or only once?

Comment: `I know C is weird when it comes to 2D arrays`, it is not weird but rather it is  poorly taught.

Answer (score 2):

> *I know C is weird when it comes to 2D arrays*

Well, this is an opinion.

C was written to aid in the writing of Unix, the operating system. An array in C is very close to the memory and the machine, as in Assembler: an array is an *address* and and *offset*. Others can say it is smart and really really fast.

And in C there is no such thing as 2D arrays or multi-dimensional arrays like in FORTRAN. There is just an array. But an array can be an array of arrays of arrays and so on...

When you declare

```
    int array[40][50];
```

you are declaring a name, `array` as a variable of a type, `int`. The presence of `[]` turns this into an array of `int`. So here `array` in an array of `int`. In fact as we have 2 sets of `[]` then
`array` is an array of 40 arrays of 50 `int`, and `array` is a pointer, the address of the first of these 2,000 `int`.

And `array[0]` is `int[50]`, `array[1]` is `int[50]` and so on.

The output of this command

```
    int array[40][50] = {0};
    printf("\
    size of `array` is %llu\n\
    size of 'int' here is %llu\n\
    size of array[0] is %llu\n",
    sizeof(array),sizeof(int),sizeof(array[0]));
```

is here

```
    size of `array` is 8000
    size of 'int' here is 4
    size of array[0] is 200
```

and you can do the math.

The array starts at `array`, has 8,000 bytes, the last element is `array[39][49]`

When you pass this to a function this address is what is passed. The type is, as you declared, `int[40][50]` and C has pointer arithmetic: based on the type size, so `array[1][19]` is an `int` and can be set as easy as `array[1][19] = 42`. Starting at `array` address (so array is a pointer at some sense), the elements are placed row after row in memory.
So if you have a pointer to `int` you can build upon this arithmetic and get the value from `array[1][19]` as

```
    array[1][19] = 42;
    int* pI      = array[1] + 19;
    printf(
        "\
    array[1][19] = %d, *pI = %d [1]\n",
        array[1][19], *pI);
    pI  = (int*) (array[0] + sizeof(array[0])/sizeof(int) + 19);
    *pI = 17;
    printf(
        "\
    array[1][19] = %d, *pI = %d [2]\n",
        array[1][19], *pI);
```

and the `printf` calls shows

```
    size of `array` is 8000
    size of 'int' here is 4
    size of array[0] is 200
    array[1][19] = 42, *pI = 42 [1]
    array[1][19] = 17, *pI = 17 [2]
```

#### `arrayCounter` just returns a number

```
int arrayCounter(int arr[40][50])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            if (arr[i][j] % 6 == 0)
                if (arr[i][j] % 5 != 0) counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

You may find easier to read this way

### complete example

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Answer to #1
int arrayCounter(int arr[40][50])
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            if (arr[i][j] % 6 == 0)
                if (arr[i][j] % 5 != 0) counter++;
    return counter;
}

int main(void)
{
    int array[40][50] = {0};
    printf(
        "\
    size of `array` is %llu\n\
    size of 'int' here is %llu\n\
    size of array[0] is %llu\n",
        sizeof(array), sizeof(int), sizeof(array[0]));

    array[1][19] = 42;
    int* pI      = array[1] + 19;
    printf(
        "\
    array[1][19] = %d, *pI = %d [1]\n",
        array[1][19], *pI);
    pI  = (int*)(array[0] + sizeof(array[0]) / sizeof(int) +
                19);
    *pI = 17;
    printf(
        "\
    array[1][19] = %d, *pI = %d [2]\n",
        array[1][19], *pI);
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            array[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1);
    printf(
        "\n    cells that are divisible by 6 but not by 5: "
        "%d\n\n",
        arrayCounter(array));
}
```

#### output

```
    size of `array` is 8000
    size of 'int' here is 4
    size of array[0] is 200
    array[1][19] = 42, *pI = 42 [1]
    array[1][19] = 17, *pI = 17 [2]

    cells that are divisible by 6 but not by 5: 533
```

Comment: *And in C there is no such thing as 2D arrays or multi-dimensional arrays* Where does that come from? [The C standard itself says otherwise](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p3):  "Successive subscript operators designate an element of a **multidimensional array object**. ..."

Comment: read _designate_ .  The abstraction is base + offset. As I said, only arrays. arrays of arrays of arrays are built upon this recurrence. This is why in `a[x][y][z]` you can use  `a[x]` as an array and `a[x][y]` as arrays... As I said refer to FORTRAN for the difference.

Comment: So, umm, you know C better than the C standard itself?

Comment: No, by no means. Just read what I said, and compare to FORTRAN, and consider what is an array of array. The standard is it: standard. But it is also language, english. Mind the word _designate_ and the examples in my previous comment...

Answer (score 1):

This prototype says that the function accepts a pointer to an array of array of 50 `int`:

```
int arrayCounter(int arr[40][50]);
```

But this call is passing a single `int` from the contents of `array`:

```
arrayCounter(array[i][j])
```

That's what the compiler message is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your code, the function `arrayCounter(int arr[40][50])` expects a parameter of an `array` type, but what you give it is `array[i][j]`, and that is a cell of `array`. That means what you give it is a member of the array, but not an array.
Since your function is defined with a `array` parameter with a fixed size, you can just call the function with the name of `array` as a parameter, like `arrayCounter(array)`.

Another problem in your code is that, since the function expects a `array`, if you want to calculate with the array, you have initialize it. In your code, `array` is initialized in the `for` loop. That means, if you call `arrayCounter` in the inner loop, it is not ready. Therefore you have to put `printf("%d", arrayCounter(array[i][j]));` after the `for` loop.

This is the edited code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int arrayCounter(int arr[40][50]) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40 ; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 50 ; j ++) {
            if(arr[i][j] % 6  == 0 && arr[i][j] % 5 !=0 ) {
                counter ++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    int array[40][50];
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            array[i][j] = (i+1) * (j+1);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", arrayCounter(array));
    return 0;
}
```

This the output:

```
533
```